# How to select only one branch in bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a list of documents

```
[
  {
    "shortName": "CA",
    "longName": "California"
  },
  {
    "shortName": "New York",
    "longName": "New York"
  },
]
```

How to configure the query to select only the first field that matches, something like `maximumSouldMatch`=1

For example if I search `New York`, it should match only `shortName` but not both, as in this case the score will be doubled

Comment: can you explain your use-case, sample and expected documents?

Comment: is it more clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`multi_match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) with the [`best_fields` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-best-fields) (which happens to be the default), the returned score will be the one of the best matching field, but not combined if both fields match (like it would be the case with `most_fields` or `cross_fields`)

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "New York",
      "fields" : [ "shortName", "longName" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as i know it will use the index data, so if we search for "New Yorks" it will also find the documents, correct?

Comment: That's a different requirement (which was to use the score of only one field and not the combined score). What you ask is still achievable using a proper analyzer on those fields, though that should be the subject of another question.

Comment: Can you please help in this question, as the new one can be marked as duplicate

Comment: It won't be a duplicate if you label it properly and explain the new requirement you have.